# I want to implement a loop script in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement a script to create an array consisting of integers from 1 to 20. Chose those elements that can be divided by 3 and multiply by 3rd power. then chose minimal value from three of its maximum elements.

Here is my code..

```js
var total = 0;
var arrVal = [];
for (var counter = 0; counter <= 20; counter++) {
     var i = 3;
     var a = 0;
     if (counter%i===0 && i!==counter) {
        arrVal.push(counter * i);
     } 
}
console.log(arrVal)
for(var i = arrVal.length; i > 0; i--) {
    if(i >= 3){ 
        max = arrVal[i];
        total = max;
    }
} 
console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to know if it is ok or not?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please post the question at Stackoverflow Code review  site.

Comment: Just would like to know If my js code is ok to give the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in an easier manner if I understand what you want to do:

```
Array(21).fill(0).map((v, i) => i).filter(v => v !== 3 && v % 3 === 0).map(v => v * 3).slice(-3)[0]
```

I'll explain each step:

1. First you create an array of size `20+1`
2. Then you fill it with zeros (because you can iterate over an array of undefined values)
3. Fill it with the index number of each element (`0`,`1`,`2`,`3`...,`20`).
4. Filter the array to get the elements that can be divided by 3 but aren't 3 (`0`,`6`,`9`,...) and you multiply them by 3 (`0`,`18`,`27`,...)
5. Slice the three last elements (`36`, `45`, `54`)
6. Take the first element which is the lowest of the three highest elements.

Comment: `v !== 3` => 3 divides 3.

Comment: what do you mean @moonwave99?